# Angular2 (final release) components fail to communicate via observable in a service

Tags: angular, angular2-services, sharedservices

I'm using `Angular v2.1`, I'm trying to make components send messages via a shared service.

I want firstly send data from the first component `company.component.ts` to the second component `modal.component.ts`.

I don't know exactly where's the problem (if it's while sending or receiving data). When I debug the receiving data, I found a Subscriber object:

```
Subscriber {closed: false, syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, syncErrorThrowable: false, isStopped: false…}
```

in the `modal.service.ts` :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {
  private sharedCompanySource = new Subject<string>();

  sharedCompany = this.sharedCompanySource.asObservable();

  getCompany(){
    return this.sharedCompany;
  }

  setCompany(_company: any){
    this.sharedCompanySource.next(_company);
  }
}
```

in the first component `company.component.ts` :

```
import { ModalService }  from './modals/modal.service';
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'company.component.html',
    providers: [
        ModalService
    ]
})
export class CompanyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private missionService: ModalService) {
     this.missionService.setCompany("hellooooooooooooooo");
  }
}
```

in the second component `modal.component.ts` :

```
import { ModalService }  from './modals/modal.service';
import { Subscription }         from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'modal.component.html',
    providers: [
        ModalService
    ]
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  subscription:Subscription;
  constructor(private missionService: ModalService) {
     this.subscription = missionService.sharedCompany.subscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both components declare

```
providers: [
    ModalService
]
```

So they don't share the service. Both have their own separate instance of ModalService. That's what providers is for.

If you want a shared service, declare it in the providers of their parent NgModule.

Note that you also don't pass any callback to `subscribe()`, so nothing will happen avan when they start sharing the same service.

Comment: Ok. so please do you have any example just to see how it works ! :)

Comment: I did it finally without observables (only simple attributs and setters, getters)